# Filter question by newest and tags

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Currently, mobile application proposes "newest" or "unanswered (my tag)" which is crippling to answer from the phone. It should be possible to filter by "newest (my tag)".

Comment: which app are you talking about?

Comment: @SagarV the Android app. I used "submit feature request" in the about dialog. It automatically post in the mets stack exchange and add tags. Which is cool.